# Creating tkinter buttons and entry boxes using for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a login menu using tkinter. My aim is to make a for loop to create all entry boxes and buttons. This works, however I need to add a command to the button to return the contents of the entry box. I am struggling to get the return of the entry box once the loop has been implemented.

I have tried to create a dictionary which holds the entry and button objects, however that doesn't work. This is what I've tried:

```
...
login_ents = {'Username': {'window': window,
                           'width': 40}}
login_btn = {'Go':
                 {'text': 'Go',
                  'window': window,
                  'object': entry_dict['Username']}}


def get_inside_username(e):
    print(e.get())
    return e.get()


def create_entry():
    ents = {}
    for ent, field in login_ents.items():  # for each label and settings
        entry = tk.Entry(field['window'], width=field['width'])
        entry.pack()
        ents[ent] = entry
    return ents


def create_button():
    btns = {}
    for btn, field in login_btn.items():
        button = tk.Button(field['window'], text=field['text'], command=get_inside_username(field['object']))
        button.pack()
        btns[btn] = button
    return btns

label_dict = create_lbs()
entry_dict = create_entry()
button_dict = create_button()
tk.mainloop()
```

I expect the entry box to print the value of what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry, Button

def printEntryValues():
    for key, val in entrys.items():
        print(val.get())

def exitTkinter():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
login_frame = Frame(root)

object_count = 2
label_values = ('Username', 'Password')
labels = {}
entrys = {}
for i in range(object_count):
    labels[f'label{i}'] = Label(login_frame, text=label_values[i])
    entrys[f'entry{i}'] = Entry(login_frame)
    labels[f'label{i}'].pack()
    entrys[f'entry{i}'].pack()

button_values = ['Exit', 'Submit']
button_commands = (exitTkinter, printEntryValues)
button_sides  = ('left', 'right')
buttons = {}
for i in range(object_count):
    buttons[f'button{i}'] = Button(login_frame, text=button_values[i], command=button_commands[i])
    buttons[f'button{i}'].pack(side=button_sides[i])

login_frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

By referencing the methods in the `button_commands` tuple I can then bind them to the buttons I create with the for loop. Be careful if you use this approach because everything relies on you getting the indexes in the tuples right (i.e `button_values[0]` must belong to the same object as `button_commands[0]`). This is easy enough to do right in this example, but if you are working on a bigger application the could end up being a pain.

Comment: Can you please explain what you changed and why? Code only answers aren't helpful to other people experiencing the same problem. Also why are you using a `dict`ionaries instead of `list`s for `labels`, `entrys` and `buttons`?

Comment: I just explained my code a bit better ! Also regarding my choice of using a dictionary instead of a list the idea is that depending on how you want to scale the code, it could be useful to configure or get the value of a widget using a more easily understandable index then just the position in the list. For example instead of `f'entry{i}'` the idex could be `f'login{n}'` allowing you to easily get the `n`th widget of the login frame, or of any other one in the future.

Comment: Put your all your explanation in answer not comment.